# How can I avoid method invocation in loop termination

Tags: java

I have following method and I trying to avoid method call from while statement but I am unable to understand what this code is doing could someone please help me optimize this code.

```
public void count(K key,AtomicReferenceArray<K> keys) {
    int index = key.hashCode() & (keys.length() - 1);

    while (!key.equals(keys.get(index)) &&
           !keys.compareAndSet(index, null, key) &&
           !key.equals(keys.get(index))) {
        if (index < keys.length() - 1) {
            index++;
        } else {
            index = 0;  //wrap
        }
    }
```

I am not able to understand what is going on here

```
while (!key.equals(keys.get(index)) &&
           !keys.compareAndSet(index, null, key) &&
           !key.equals(keys.get(index)))
```

Comment: Which bit do you not understand, exactly?

Comment: @JonSkeet the condition in while part

Comment: Which part of the condition? It's three method calls; the second will only be called if the first condition is true, and the third will only be called if the second condition is true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief translation:
Start at index, and loop through the array with wrapping, until:

You found the key you were looking for
OR
You found a null key and managed to insert your key in there
OR
A race condition occurred and another thread inserted your key in the position you are examining.